# Display manager does not start at startup

Tags: xorg, display-manager

Running `sudo start lightdm` from the command line seems to work fine though. Neither `exec xdm` or `xdm` or `sudo xdm` or `sudo exec xdm` do though.

Things I have already tried -

- selecting various options from `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xdm` - whatever option I choose, the problem remains
- Checking `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` contains an absolute path, and that this is the real location of the display manager - `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` contains `/usr/bin/xdm` and `file /usr/bin/xdm` gives `ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV)...` which sounds right

Also, `/var/log/dmesg` contains lots of suspicious entries like

```
[   21.997255] systemd-udevd[1005]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/socket:@
/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event' 'socket:@/
org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event': No such file or directory
```

but I'm not sure what this means or even if it is relevant. Certainly, `file /lib/udev/socket` gives `` /lib/udev/socket: ERROR: cannot open `/lib/udev/socket' (No such file or directory) `` and `ls /lib/udev/ | grep socket` gives `pcmcia-socket-startup`. `locate udev_event` and `locate socket | grep socket$` gives this -

```
/etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/avahi-daemon.socket
/etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/gpsd.socket
/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.socket
/lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket
/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd-control.socket
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
/lib/systemd/system/dbus.target.wants/dbus.socket
/lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/dbus.socket
/lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/systemd-udevd-control.socket
/lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket
/usr/lib/cups/backend-available/socket
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-websocket
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-websocket
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/sockets.target.wants/avahi-daemon.socket
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/sockets.target.wants/gpsd.socket
```

and `locate udev_event` returns no result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using debian/ubuntu, check the existence of `/etc/init.d/xdm` and `/etc/rc2.d/xdm`, whereas the latter should be a symlink to the former. If the latter doesn't exist, you can make one, or use the `rcconf` tool to create one.

P.S. Sorry I've never heard `lightdm`, but the package `xdm` itself should be working fine. And I don't think there's anything to do with the `dmesg` information.

Answer (score -1):

It's a systemd problem. Apparently most display managers are incompatible with systemd as they use PAM recursively. just google login manager and systemd funkmuscle

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  There are also significant other problems with this answer.  There is nothing to salvage with this answer honestly, numerous instances of "systemd" instead of "system", but in the end it doesn't actually answer the question.